# Application using wrong template function definition in C++ file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017

I have a class that stores a specific variable, and I use templates to specify the type. This is important, because OpenGL has different functions to update these values in the shader. Here's the header `shader_variable.h`.

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value == false>>
class ShaderVariable : public Base::ShaderVariable
{
public:
    ShaderVariable(const std::string& a_Name, ShaderProgram& a_Program) :
        Base::ShaderVariable(a_Name, (Liane::Base::ShaderProgram&)a_Program, (void*)&m_Value),
        m_Name(a_Name)
    {
    }

    operator const T&() const { return m_Value; }
    const T& GetValue() const { return m_Value; }


    void Update() override;
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    T m_Value;
};
```

in the CPP file, I have the following definition

```
template<> void ShaderVariable<glm::vec3>::Update()
{
    std::cout << "Updating vec3" << std::endl;
    glUniform3fv(m_Reference, 1, glm::value_ptr(m_Value));
}

template<> void ShaderVariable<glm::vec4>::Update()
{
    std::cout << "Updating vec4" << std::endl;
    glUniform4fv(m_Reference, 1, glm::value_ptr(m_Value));
}

template<> void ShaderVariable<glm::mat3>::Update()
{
    std::cout << "Updating mat3" << std::endl;
    glUniformMatrix3fv(m_Reference, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_Value));
}

template<> void ShaderVariable<glm::mat4>::Update()
{
    std::cout << "Updating mat4" << std::endl;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_Reference, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_Value));
}
```

And in the main function, I make a `glm::mat4` ShaderVariable first, and a `glm::vec3` second. If I do this, everything compiles fine, and all ShaderVariables call the glm::mat4 Update().

Now, usually I put my template definitions in the header file, but due to the complexity I prefered the cpp file instead. Is there a way to mitigate this issue?

I also added 
`template class ShaderVariable<glm::vec3>;
        template class ShaderVariable<glm::vec4>;
        template class ShaderVariable<glm::mat3>;`

    to the bottom, as another question's answer suggested it, but this does nothing for my issue.

Comment: Playing with the order and visibility of templates, their declarations and specializations is a delicate matter. The standard itself [considers it a fire hazard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.expl.spec#7).

Comment: You need to at least declare your explicit specializations in the header. "**[temp.expl.spec]/6** If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required."